# Liferay - Hook for GroupWrapper

Tags: hook, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to override the getDescriptiveName() method in com.liferay.portal.model.Group

I found a wrapper (com.liferay.portal.model.GroupWrapper), so I tried to write a hook as written in the documentation :

`liferay-hook.xml`:

```xml
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portal.model.GroupWrapper</service-type>
    <service-impl>fr.villedeniort.hook.expando.GroupWrapperImpl</service-impl>
</service>
```

`fr.villedeniort.hook.expando.GroupWrapperImpl.java`:

```java
public class GroupWrapperImpl extends GroupWrapper {
    public GroupWrapperImpl(Group group) {
    super(group);
}

@Override
public java.lang.String getDescriptiveName()
  throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException,
  com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
    return super.getDescriptiveName();
}
```

When the hook is deployed, it raises an exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fr.villedeniort.hook.expando.GroupWrapperImpl.<init>(com.liferay.portal.model.GroupWrapper)
```

I browse the code I found out that it breaks at this part for a reason I ignore:

```java
Constructor<?> serviceImplConstructor = serviceImplClass.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] {serviceTypeClass});
```

At this point, variables have theses values:

```
serviceType "com.liferay.portal.model.GroupWrapper" (id=14829)
serviceImpl "fr.villedeniort.hook.expando.GroupWrapperImpl" (id=14830)
serviceTypeClass Class<T> (com.liferay.portal.model.GroupWrapper) (id=14831)
serviceImplClass Class<T> (fr.villedeniort.hook.expando.GroupWrapperImpl) (id=14832)
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to hook other classes than Services, so I had to find a different way. For my case, I hooked a JSP and wrote my own method to get the right descriptive name from the hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should have also a constructor without any argument. Now you have one with constuctor arguments, but there is no pure class constructor that java searches when it makes class instance. After calling the pure constructor java then calls the argumented one.

I had similar case in some other context and this was the solution. `<init>` tag on the error message refers on this kind of issue.